# Send messages from server to websocket clients

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish

I'm building a websocket application using glassfish I need in a given event my server to send message to all connected clients. I can send and receive messages from both, but I am not able to use the class server to send messages.

My server class has the following body:

`@ApplicationScoped
 @ServerEndpoint("/actions")
public class DeviceWebSocketServer {`

```
@Inject
private DeviceSessionHandler sessionHandler;

@OnOpen
public void open(Session session) {
    sessionHandler.addSession(session);
}

@OnClose
public void close(Session session) {
    sessionHandler.removeSession(session);
}

@OnError
public void onError(Throwable error) {
    Logger.getLogger(DeviceWebSocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, error);
}

@OnMessage
public void handleMessage(String message, Session session) {

    System.out.println("Chegou uma mensagem: " + message);
    System.out.println("Na sessao: " + session.getId());

    try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(message))) {
        JsonObject jsonMessage = reader.readObject();

        if ("add".equals(jsonMessage.getString("action"))) {
            Device device = new Device();
            device.setName(jsonMessage.getString("name"));
            device.setDescription(jsonMessage.getString("description"));
            device.setType(jsonMessage.getString("type"));
            device.setStatus("Off");
            sessionHandler.addDevice(device);
        }

        if ("remove".equals(jsonMessage.getString("action"))) {
            int id = (int) jsonMessage.getInt("id");
            sessionHandler.removeDevice(id);
        }

        if ("toggle".equals(jsonMessage.getString("action"))) {
            int id = (int) jsonMessage.getInt("id");
            sessionHandler.toggleDevice(id);
        }
    }

}
```

How do I send messages to customers after receiving an event? Should I instantiate my class server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a example on howto send messages to all connected clients in this whiteboard app:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-websocketapi.html

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/whiteboardendpoint", encoders = {FigureEncoder.class}, decoders = {FigureDecoder.class})
public class MyWhiteboard {

    private static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

   @OnMessage
   public void broadcastFigure(Figure figure, Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
    System.out.println("broadcastFigure: " + figure);
    for (Session peer : peers) {
        if (!peer.equals(session)) {
            peer.getBasicRemote().sendObject(figure);
        }
    }
}
```